# Fail loading driver (SQL Server, JBoss, Maven)

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, jboss

I'm trying to load JBoss Server with SQL Server configuration in standalone.xml and -ds.xml, and when I start the server it returns the following error:

```
15:21:38,092 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "sqlserver")
]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver]"

JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.sqlserver (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/pontualpro-DS]
```

My pom.xml configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My -ds.xml configuration:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/pontualpro-DS" pool-name="pontualpro" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:667</connection-url>
    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>sa</user-name>
        <password>sa</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

My standalone.xml configuration:

```
<drivers>
    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
    <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
        <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

The sqljdbc jar file is already in repository file

> .m2>repository>com>microsoft>sqlserver>sqljdbc4>4.0>sqljdbc4-4.0.jar

If someone can help me I will be greatfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that jar file is in server directory, usually it's something like

`jboss/server/production/lib` or similar path.

Jboss will not use jar from your build. It MUST be in it's lib path

Comment: The jar file is in the server directory and I already try the tag <driver-class> insteaned <xa-datasource-class> =(

Comment: I struggled a lot when I was first time installing jboss, db, etc. I finally found everything regarding standalone.xml here: https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/amartin-blog/2012/02/08/how-to-set-up-a-postgresql-jdbc-driver-on-jboss-7 . Maybe it can help you too if you change the driver type/name

Comment: The file module.xml is it really necessary? Because when I put "h2" driver it works  without problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the jboss application server but my guess would be that an SQL driver must be provided by the appication server. I think the sqljdbc4-4.0.jar must be added to the "libs" of your application server.

Comment: The maven framework already links the lib in .m2 repository into the project.

Comment: I'm only familiar with Tomcat and Weblogic and those both have lib folders. If you say maven is taking care of that, maybe you could try adding `<scope>provided</scope>` to indicate that it is a jar which has to be provided by the application server?

Answer (score 0):

The driver class you gave is not correct. You should give the full name 
com.microsoft.sqlserver

see the reference as an example here: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/Using_other_Databases.html#Using_other_Databases-Using_MySQL_as_the_Default_DataSource